# Why 'inject with insertBefore avoid appendChild errors'?

Tags: javascript, appendchild

On the article [How, When, And Why Script Loaders Are Appropriate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/msdn10/hh227261(v=msdn.10)), I found the following comment without a clear explanation:

```js
// Very simple asynchronous script-loader

// Create a new script element
var script      = document.createElement('script');

// Find an existing script element on the page (usually the one this code is in)
var firstScript = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];

// Set the location of the script
script.src      = "http://example.com/myscript.min.js";

// Inject with insertBefore to avoid appendChild errors
firstScript.parentNode.insertBefore( script, firstScript );
```

What errors they are avoiding by using `insertBefore` instead of `appendChild`?

Why would `appendChild` cause any errors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like it's for a bug in IE6, and to avoid problems with the absence of a head tag.

Good description for script injection techniques and a little bit of history and context: http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2010/05/11/appendchild-vs-insertbefore/

Specifically this issue: https://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/2709

```
head = document.getElementsByTagName ("head")[0] || 
    document.documentElement;
// Use insertBefore instead of appendChild to circumvent an IE6 bug.
// This arises when a base node is used (#2709 and #4378).
head.insertBefore(script, head.firstChild);
```

Incidentally I've had to do a lot of work on IE6 support, and I've never had this problem.  I avoided using the head tag for other reasons and used insertBefore so it would be easier to clean up injected scripts when needed, so I guess I just got lucky.